# SQL SERVER (TSQL) SUM of inverse DateDiff (SQL or Stored Procedure)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datediff

I have a tricky `SQL` to create, having this table:

```
+-----------------------+
| Employee Login Logout |
+-----------------------+
| 1        08:30 08:50  |
| 1        09:00 10:00  |
| 1        10:20 11:00  |
+-----------------------+
```

I need a sql to sum all the break times:

```
08:50 -> 09:00 = 10 minutes +
10:00 -> 10:20 = 20 minutes =
30 minutes in total
```

So I need somehow to go over each record and using the `datediff` method `sum` the duration of the breaks between the records.

Is there any easy way to do it using `SQL` or `Stored Procedure`?

Comment: Take the diff between the last logout and first login, and then subtract the sums of all the individual records.

Comment: Is there any Date column in this table? Or only EmployeeID?

Comment: Yes, it is actually: DateTime not just time: 01/01/2015 08:30 - 01/01/2015 08:50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS commented by @thebjorn, you could first get the difference between the first login and the last logout (work shift) and subtract the `SUM` of difference of each login-logout pair (actual time you're working). The result would be the total time you're not working or your break time.

```
;WITH SampleData(Employee, Login, Logout) AS(
    SELECT 1, CAST('08:30' AS TIME), CAST('08:50' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CAST('09:00' AS TIME), CAST('10:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CAST('10:20' AS TIME), CAST('11:00' AS TIME)
)
SELECT 
    Employee,
    TotalBreakTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Login), MAX(Logout)) -  SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Login, Logout))
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY Employee
```

---

Using `LAG` function

```
;WITH SampleData(Employee, Login, Logout) AS(
    SELECT 1, CAST('08:30' AS TIME), CAST('08:50' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CAST('09:00' AS TIME), CAST('10:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, CAST('10:20' AS TIME), CAST('11:00' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, CAST('10:00' AS TIME), CAST('10:30' AS TIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('11:30' AS TIME)
)
,CteBreakTime AS(
    SELECT *,
        BreakTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(Logout) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Login), Login)
    FROM SampleData
)
SELECT
    Employee,
    TotalBreakTime = SUM(BreakTime) 
FROM CteBreakTime
GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: Does the use of "WITH" save process time in a SQL? instead of using SubQueries?